# GridBagLayout Horizontal alignment

Tags: java

How can i align everything to the center of the frame ? In my example code, the JLabel doesnt occupies the same % of space as the button.Its about 10% label and 90% button. How can i make them both have the same amount of space ? This is my code:

```
class Animation extends JPanel {
    JLabel lab = new JLabel("A");
    JButton but = new JButton("BUTTTTTTTOOOOOOOOOOOOON");
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    public Animation(){
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0 ;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(lab,c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        add(but, c);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fram = new JFrame();
        fram.add(new Animation());
        fram.pack();
        fram.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two of them into a 2x1 GridLayout -- it forces the same dimensions on each cell.

```
public Animation()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout());
    add(lab);
    add(but);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, haven't thinked about that.

Comment: But what if JLabel changes his size? Its "A" at first but what if it gets to be "AAAAAAA" ? How can i add space between him and the next component ?

Comment: There are various ways to add space between components, but which one to use depends on all you want to do.  Do you want the grid to change its size to accommodate different lengths of strings?  Do you want a constant gap between these two elements?  Do you want the gap to change sizes?  I find that, in UI programming, it is best to think through the behavior you want and design all of it at once; the tools best for one part may not fit for another part, and choosing the best layout (or other UI tool) may well depend on another piece of behavior you want.

Comment: I want the gap to change size.

Comment: Change size how and when?  Take a step back, and think about what you want for the whole screen.  It is difficult to have any confidence in solving your problem if I/we only know what part of the problem is.  You asked about making the components the same size, now you want a gap.  I can propose ways to do that, but would much prefer knowing overall what you want and what your problem is doing it; attempting to correct it piecemeal is just asking for frustration.